# Scala-fy a java function?

Tags: scala

I've recently switched my assignment from Java to Scala. However, it still looks like java. 
For example, the function below does a search on a range tree, and inside there I do some "isInstanceOf" checks.

However - replacing them with "match" seems like it would only take up more space. Can anyone suggest some improvements on how to "scalify" this code?

```
def rangeSearch2D(treeRoot: Node, lower: Data2D, upper: Data2D, 
         visited: Visited): Seq[Data2D] = {

    if (treeRoot == null) {
      // return empty list
  return Vector()
}
// increment visit count
if (visited != null)
  visited.visit2D(treeRoot)

var results = ArrayBuffer[Data2D]()

// Find nearest common ancestor with value between lower.x and upper.x
var common: Node = commonAncestor(treeRoot, lower, upper, visited)

if (common.isInstanceOf[LeafNode]) {
  return Vector(common.asInstanceOf[LeafNode].data)
}

/** Common non-leaf node, must process subtree */
/** Process left subtree */
var current = common.left

while (!current.isInstanceOf[LeafNode]) {
  if (visited != null)
    visited.visit2D(current)

  //Find a path from current to lower.x
  if (lower.x <= current.midRange) {
    results.appendAll(rangeSearch1D(current.right.subTree, 
                        lower, upper, visited))
    current = current.left
  } else {
    current = current.right
  }
}
//Check if current leaf node is in range
if (inRange(current, lower, upper)) {

  results.append(current.asInstanceOf[LeafNode].data)
}
/** Process right subtree */
current = common.right

while (!current.isInstanceOf[LeafNode]) {
  if (visited != null)
    visited.visit2D(current)

  //Find a path from current to upper.x
  if (upper.x >= current.midRange) {

    results.appendAll(rangeSearch1D(current.left.subTree, 
                        lower, upper, visited))
    current = current.right
  } else {
    current = current.left
  }
}
//Check if current leaf node is in range
    if (inRange(current, lower, upper)) {
      results.append(current.asInstanceOf[LeafNode].data)
    }

    return results
  }
```

Comment: Instead of a Leaf/non-Leaf categorization by type, consider using [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/Either.html). Then there is no instanceOf/cast required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first you can get rid of `null`, replacing the parameters that might be `null` with `Option`. In the code, you then change

```
if (visited != null)
  visited.visit2D(x)
```

with

```
visited foreach (_ visit2D x)
```

Both while loops can be replaced with recursive functions. Instead of adding the result to a mutable variable, you can pass it as an immutable accumulator parameter in the recursive function.

If `Node` has an extractor, you could use a case guard to make the `midrange` test. Doesn't add much, but is more idiomatic.

I get the feeling that both while loops can be subsumed into a single recursion, but I haven't considered the algorithm enough to decided about that. If so, you could get away with the `common` early return.

By the way, there's a bug there, since there might not be a common ancestor within the range.

Comment: `apply` on the `Option` companion object can do the right thing here: `Option(visited) foreach (_ visit2D current)`

Comment: @Kevin Sure, but it doesn't fix the API requiring clients to pass a `null`.

Comment: @Daniel - True, but that's sometimes not fixable at all if Java interop or third-party libraries are involved.

Comment: Oh, there will always be common ancestor, as long as the two nodes are on the same "level". Anyways don't worry about the logic its correct. But regarding your "foreach" - isn't that a loop? But I am only checking a single value?

Comment: It is a pretty standard way to do something optionally. `None.foreach(f)` does nothing, `Some(x).foreach(f)` calls `f(x)`.

Comment: so "visited foreach (_ visit2D x)" calls "_" on visited?

Comment: @drozzy `visited foreach (_ visit2D x)` calls `.visit2D(x)` on whatever is inside `visited` (which we are assuming to be an `Option`), if anything.

Answer (score 3):

To Scala-fy the code above there are a few fairly general steps you could take:

- Reduce the number of **if** statements and replace casts and
  type tests with pattern matching
- Eliminate **while** statements with
  recursive functions / methods or
  library methods (such as folds)
- Eliminate vars by passing
  accumulators into function / method
  calls and assign the result to recover the final accumulation
- Reduce assignments by using values
  returned by multi-block statements such as **if** and **try catch**
- Eliminate nulls using **Option** types
- Eliminate the **return** keyword to guard
  against missing permutations
- Only leave out an **else** block / statement if it performs a No-Op (the compiler should catch broken assignments from an **if** without an **else**)
- Use extractors, if possible, to decompose hierarchies easily in pattern matches.
- If the code doesn't read well refactor and introduce well named helper functions / methods

Answer (score 2):

A first step could be something like this, but I'm sure there are more opportunities (e.g. breaking the method in smaller steps [and avoiding things like currentN by this], finding a way to unify `loop0` and `loop1`, which are ugly, replacing the `ArrayBuffer` by an immutable structure, making visited an `Option`).

```
  def rangeSearch2D(treeRoot: Node, lower: Data2D, upper: Data2D, visited: Visited): Seq[Data2D] = 
  if (treeRoot == null) Vector() // return empty list
  else {

    // increment visit count
    if (visited != null)
      visited.visit2D(treeRoot)

    val results = ArrayBuffer[Data2D]()

    // Find nearest common ancestor with value between lower.x and upper.x
    val (current0,current2) = commonAncestor(treeRoot, lower, upper, visited) match {
      case leafNode:LeafNode => return Vector(leafNode.data)
      case common => (common.left, common.right)
    }     

    def loop0(current: Node):Node = current match {
      case _:LeafNode => current
      case _ =>  if (visited != null) visited.visit2D(current)
        if (lower.x <= current.midRange) {
          results.appendAll(rangeSearch1D(current.right.subTree, 
                                          lower, upper, visited))
          current.left
        } else current.right
    }

    val current1 = loop0(current0)


    //Check if current leaf node is in range
    if (inRange(current1, lower, upper))  results.append(current1.asInstanceOf[LeafNode].data)

    def loop1(current: Node):Node = current match {
      case _:LeafNode => current
      case _ =>  if (visited != null) visited.visit2D(current)
        if (upper.x >= current.midRange) {
          results.appendAll(rangeSearch1D(current.left.subTree, 
                                          lower, upper, visited))
          current.right
        } else current.left
    }

    val current3 = loop1(current2)

    //Check if current leaf node is in range
    if (inRange(current3, lower, upper)) 
      results.append(current3.asInstanceOf[LeafNode].data)

    results
  }
```

Comment: Did you just define a function inside Another function??

Comment: @drozzy: Yes, technically a method in a method, but this is allowed in Scala. But only if you reach the spiritual plane of the lesser patriarchs you are allowed to write methods *in methods* **in methods**.